# How do I remove a specific string from some strings in a list?

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out a more universal fix for my code and having a hard time with it. This is what I have:

```
lst = ['Thursday, June ##', 'some string', 'another string', 'etc', 'Friday, June ##', 'more strings', 'etc']
```

I'm trying to remove everything after the comma in the strings that contain commas (which can only be the day of the week strings).

My current fix that works is:

```
new_lst = [x[:-9] if ',' in x else x for x in lst]
```

But this won't work for every month since they're not always going to be a 4 letter string ('June'). I've tried splitting at the commas and then removing any string that starts with a space but it wasn't working properly so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a list comprehension along with `split()` here:

```py
lst = ['Thursday, June ##', 'some string', 'another string', 'etc', 'Friday, June ##', 'more strings', 'etc']
output = [x.split(',', 1)[0] for x in lst]
print(output)
# ['Thursday', 'some string', 'another string', 'etc', 'Friday', 'more strings', 'etc']
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is perfect, much appreciated. What does the [0] do in the split method here?

Comment: `split()` returns a list, so the `[0]` is the first item in that list

Answer (score 0):

With `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = [re.sub(r',.*', '', x) for x in lst]
>>> lst
['Thursday,', 'some string', 'another string', 'etc', 'Friday,', 'more strings', 'etc']
```

However, this is slower than the `split` answer

Comment: Oh, thank you! I'm actually trying to remove the comma, how would I alter it to do so? Not familiar with regex

Comment: @bluetortuga, fixed. The second argument of `re.sub` is the replacement value. It's now nothing, so the comma will be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search` in the following way:

```
import re
lst = ['Thursday, June ##', 'some string', 'another string', 'etc', 'Friday, June ##', 'more strings', 'etc']
for i, msg in enumerate(lst):
    match = re.search(",", msg)
    if match != None:
        lst[i] = msg[:match.span()[0]]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['Thursday', 'some string', 'another string', 'etc', 'Friday', 'more strings', 'etc']
```